# CouldNotLoadArgumentException thrown when JNLP Property Value Length is more than 32 characters (since JDK 8u40)

Tags: java, properties, java-8, java-web-start, jnlp

Since Java Update 8u40 we have a problem with our application. If jnlp File contains properties  with value more than 32 signs, for example: `<property name="javaws.platform-url" value="http://test-server1.vm.local/NetServer/AppControllerServlet"/>` the application crushes by starting with following error:

```
CouldNotLoadArgumentException[ Angegebene Datei/URL konnte nicht geladen werden: C:\Users\testuser\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_cache4814352828741789694.tmp]
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @user2864740 it means 'character' or 'letter' or 'symbol'

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by using *argument*-Tag instead of *property*-Tag. For example:

```
<application-desc main-class="de.test.application.assistant.MainApplication">
  <argument>http://test-server1.vm.local/NetServer/AppControllerServlet</argument>
</application-desc>
```